# Can a testnet node have a separate bitcoin.conf file?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, testnet

When running `bitcoind` on testnet, can I put its configuration settings in a separate `bitcoin.conf` file from the "real" `bitcoin.conf` file?  I would like to be able to run two nodes concurrently, one on the live network and one on the test network, each with its own configuration settings.

Answer (score 3):

By default `bitcoind` will look for the file `bitcoin.conf` in its `datadir` directory, whether running on testnet or mainnet.  But you could use the `-conf` option when starting one or both of the daemons, to point it to a different file.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is currently not possible to have network specific configuration files. However there are currently open pull requests which enable such functionality.